# Mod_security rule exception for url/arg

Tags: mod-security

An image on our site is flagging a modsec rule I am trying to add a rule exception for only that occurrence.  The number at the start of the flagged string is a session number, so I have added a regex to my rule.

I've tried various permutations but had no joy and would appreciate some advice.

Blocked URI:
https://www.website.com/application/login?0--preLoginHeaderPanel-companyLogo

Modsec log snippet:
[file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"] [line "65"] [id "**942100**"] [msg "SQL Injection Attack Detected via libinjection"] [data "Matched Data: 1c found within **ARGS_NAME:0--preLoginHeaderPanel-companyLogo: 0--preLoginHeaderPanel-companyLogo**"]

Attempted exceptions (within apache.conf):
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 942100 !ARGS_NAMES:'[0-9][0-9]?--preLoginHeaderPanel-companyLogo'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Rule Set *Dev on Duty* here. Rule 942100 is one of our 'LibInjection' rules. LibInjection is quite opaque (it's a third party library/operator), so you're correct that a rule exclusion is the way to fix this issue.

The use of regular expressions in this context follows a specific form. They need to be sandwiched inside forward slashes, like so:

```
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 942100 "!ARGS_NAMES:/^[0-9][0-9]?--preLoginHeaderPanel-companyLogo/"
```

I added in a starting anchor at the beginning of the regular expression. You might want to think whether anchoring at the end is a good idea, as well.

For more examples and information, we have some great documentation on this here: https://coreruleset.org/docs/concepts/false_positives_tuning/#support-for-regular-expressions

Comment: Ah, Xanadu; you champion - thank you very much.  I took your advice and anchored the end, too.  I'm not sure how I missed that page during my furious Googling.